# Slide Up Panel with View Pager Title Strip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slideup

I am using this [LIBRARY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Egc.jpg) for my slide up panel. every thing is working fine with a simple layout.
Now my question is , how can I insert a pager title strip in that panel so that I can make it my View pager working on it with multiple fragments.

[image: first image with panel and pager title strip]

[image: slide up to view panel]

First image is title strip at bottom
second is slide up and sliding fragments

Comment: Here is good tutorial http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/tabnvigation-like-google-play-store-app.html

Comment: ok this link is working.. but not exactly what i want ! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your previous post, I'm assuming you're using this library (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

This library requires that you have 2 children views. The first one being the main layout and the second one the actual sliding view. Now, your sliding view is just a placeholder, so you can place anything you want in there. If you want to add a ViewPager, this is how you can do it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- Top Panel -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sliding Panel -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What we have here is the main layout of our Activity (RelativeLayout) and we're adding the `SlidingPanelLayout` to it. Inside this Layout, we've defined our main layout to be a LinearLayout (Top Panel) and a second LinearLayout (Sliding Panel) which is the actual sliding view. Now, all we need to do is add a ViewPager to this sliding panel.

Comment: can you post some screen shots of this ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't upload screenshots since the app hasn't been released yet. But it's actually exactly like the Google Play Music app. You have the main view which shows you your list of albums and when you slide the panel up, you basically have access to a ViewPager which shows the current playlist.

Comment: can i put gesture on thjat so that slide left to right will do something like Google Play Music(Changing the currently playing music) ??

Comment: Well, if your bottom panel has a ViewPager, all you need to do is add fragments or views to it. The gestures will automatically be handled by the ViewPager.

Comment: without sliding it up?

Comment: No, the functionality is 100% the same as the Google Music App. You will first need to slide the bottom panel up, which will make the ViewPager at the bottom accessible. Then you can swipe through it.

Comment: i have added a view pager and its not sliding along fragments :(

Comment: its stuck i dont know what just happned